# Как закоммитить часть определенного файла, при условии, что git отслеживает и другие файлы?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

## Преамбула

Есть команда `git add --patch`, которая позволяет определить, какие изменения пойдут в коммит.

Есть команда `git commit -v <file>`, позволяющая закоммитить определенный файл.

### Вопрос:

Как мне закоммитить патч для определенного файла? При условии, что ранее была выполнена команда `git add <some.other.file>`?

## Описание:

Рассмотрим череду следующих команд:

1. Создали и закоммитили файл `a.txt`
2. Создали файл `b.txt` и добавили его в git, но не закоммитили изменения
3. Изменили файл `a.txt`
4. Вызвали команду `git add --patch a.txt` и выбрали только одно изменение в файле
5. Попытались закоммитить изменения с помощью команды `git commit -v` - оказалось, что файл `b.txt` также попадает в коммит
6. Попытались закоммитить изменения с помощью команды `git commit -v a.txt` - оказалось, что теперь файл коммитится полностью

---

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/soon/Src/Git/CommitPatch/.git/

$ cat a.txt
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
versions of Lorem Ipsum.

$ git add a.txt
$ git commit a.txt -m "Added a.txt"
[master (root-commit) 697228d] Added a.txt
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt

$ touch b.txt
$ git add b.txt 
$ cat a.txt
A line
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Another line

$ git add a.txt --patch
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 2061a78..0ea2f5a 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+A line
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
 Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? y
@@ -6,3 +7,4 @@ typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
 with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
 recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
 versions of Lorem Ipsum.
+Another line
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,g,e,?]? n

$ git commit -v
# Commits both patch to the a.txt file and whole b.txt file

$ git commit -v a.txt
# Commits whole a.txt file

$ git commit --patch -v a.txt
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 986cf0b..0ea2f5a 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -7,3 +7,4 @@ typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
 with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
 recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
 versions of Lorem Ipsum.
+Another line
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? n

# Behaves like git commit -v
```

Есть, разумеется, вариант с `git rm`, но он мне не нравится ввиду своей костыльности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

1. Индексируем нужную нам часть `a.txt` (ту, которую хотим в коммит)

   ```
   git add --patch a.txt
   ```
2. Прикарманиваем неиндексированные изменения. Неиндексированная часть `a.txt` тоже уходит в карман.

   ```
   git stash save --keep-index
   ```
3. Делаем коммит только из файла `a.txt`.

   ```
   git commit a.txt -m'message'
   ```
4. Достаем из кармана неиндексированные изменения, в том числе отложенную часть `a.txt`

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```

Comment: @soon: вроде придумал, как обойти через карман — попробуйте.

Comment: Да, сработало - спасибо!

Comment: @soon: отлично ) Вообще, досадно, что `git commit filename` работает не с индексом, а с рабочей областью — было бы удобно.

Comment: Я, кстати, не нашел аналогичный вопрос в англоязычном сегменте интернета. Есть вероятность, что я плохо искал, потому что запроса лучше `git commit patch` я не придумал. Тем не менее, не подать ли это как proposal в git? Конечно, не такая уж и частая проблема, но меня несколько смутило, почему `git commit --patch -v a.txt` заграбастал себе еще и изменения в файле `b.txt`.

Comment: @soon тоже подумал о proposal. Знаете, как?

Comment: Судя по README.md в [репозитории git](https://github.com/git/git), можно написать на `git@vger.kernel.org` по поводу багов, фичей и всего такого.

Answer (score 1):

Просто сделайте `git stash` **перед** тем, как выполнять команду `git add --patch`.

Comment: Не сработало - `a.txt` тоже спрятался. У @NickVolynkin было аналогичное предложение - Вы можете увидеть его в истории правок ответа

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, после `git stash` нечего будет индексировать.